# Calculate the gradient of this multiple dimensional function using Python, NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

How can I write code to compute the gradient of the following question?
F(x) = sum(x^2), for n-dimensional x

I tried doing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7PC2.png)this just by simply calculating gradients

Comment: `x = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4) ; np.gradient(x**2)`?

Comment: @mozway What do the arange and reshape do here?

Comment: It's just to create a dummy example of a n-dimensional array

Comment: @mozway but it doesnt give a correct output. I mean the gradients

Comment: I don't know, you did not explain what you want nor provide an example

Comment: The problem gives this f(x) = sum(x^2), where x is an n dimensional vector. And I should compute the gradient of the function

Comment: please provide a minimal example

Comment: @mozway I posted a pic

Comment: @mozway I added an image to the post

Comment: @mozway in other words I have to compute the gradient of euclidean norm of x.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.